# Create minor version from old tag in Github?

Tags: github, tagging, hotfix

I have an application for which we may create a hotfix branch from old tag (which is live in production). Current TAGs can be far ahead of that, as we may not release changes too quickly.

How can I create a minor version in continuation of the old tag now?
For example,

```
Production TAG - 0.20.0
Expected TAG - 0.20.1
Generated TAG - 0.29.1
```

I'm using `https://github.com/mathieudutour/github-tag-action` v6 to generate the tag.

The GH action usage looks something like below:

```
   uses: mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v6.1
   with:
    github_token: ***
    default_bump: minor
    custom_release_rules: fix:patch,feat:minor,perf:major
    dry_run: true
    release_branches: main,hotfix
    default_prerelease_bump: prerelease
    create_annotated_tag: false
    fetch_all_tags: false
```

Comment: You seem to be using some Actions workflow, which you don't show, so it's very hard to help. Generally, if you want to backport some fix to an old tag, you'd create a new branch based on that old tag, apply the fix (for example via cherry-picking and potentially fixing that), and then tag the latest commit in that new branch. Manually, if need be, since it sounds like you're using some automation that guesses the next version.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminW. I updated the question with more details. Could you please check now?